# cotton-top tamarins also spend most of their lives in the trees. My question is about why not most of their live ? why lives?

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses, verb-agreement, subjects

I don't understand (most of their lives) is singular or plural ? what make this sentence singular for what reason ?

Comment: Many tamarins, many lives. You could say _life_ as well, though.

Comment: i want to know if say most of their lives = does it mean every single live ..or if say most of their life = does it mean community as a whole .

Comment: Each individual spends most of _its life_ in the trees. The sentence talks about the species in general, so _their lives_.

Comment: *Tammy, the tamarin, spent most of her life in a zoo.* Singular tamarin, singular life. *Tammy's family, all eight of them, spent most of their lives in trees.*  Many tamarin, many lives.

Comment: What @user405662 said. Plural is "logical", but singular is also fine in contexts like *Amphibious mammals ... spend [**most of their life**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22most+of+their+life+in+aquatic%22) in aquatic environments*.